# Passing containers between JFrame and JDialog causing missing panels?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, restart, jdialog

As for testing-reasons I tried to open a JDialog window with the panel and its contents of the main application frame. As I already had anything in there I wanted to see if I could simply set the JDialogs contentPane to the one I passed over. So in simplyfied form this came together:

testsforSO.java :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testsforSO extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3890178393751567629L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testsforSO frame = new testsforSO();
                    frame.setSize(300, 300);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public testsforSO() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("I am the Frame");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnRestart = new JButton("Restart");
        btnRestart.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
        btnRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                testsforSO.main(null);
                dispose();
            }
        });
        panel.add(btnRestart);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        repaint();

// -----------DELETE These comments-------------
//      JDialog myDialg = new JDialog(this);
//      myDialg.setContentPane(panel);
//      myDialg.setVisible(true);
//      myDialg.setSize(300,300);
//      myDialg.setLocation(new Point(250, 250));
//      myDialg.setTitle("I am Dialog from within the script");

        myDialog.main(panel);
    }
}
```

and myDialog.java :

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class myDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7079322237622743228L;

    public static void main(Container myContainer) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    myDialog frame = new myDialog(myContainer);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setContentPane(myContainer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public myDialog(Container myContainer) {
        setContentPane(myContainer);

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        setBounds(200,200,200,200);

    }

}
```

When starting the main frame I assumed it would contain the restarting button as well as the dialog does. But interestingly it was only the dialog with the button.
However when hitting it, the main frame properly restarted, a second dialog was set up and it contained the button again. This time however the main frame had the button as well, just without any function. Clicking on it does absolutely nothing.

Then I tried further and checked if that behaviour would change if I added the dialog directly into the main applications code (see the commented lines) and, starting the application once again only the dialog in its own class showed the button. Even hitting this one now restarted properly but the button won't show up on any other window except the lonely declared dialog.

What am I missing here and how could I refactor my code to work properly if even at all in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that Swing components can only be present in one container, and while you may see the visual residue of a component in a container, the actual component is only present in the last container added to.

Myself, if I wanted dialog and jframe to have the same content pane components, I'd create a factory method to create the contentPane, and then use it to create two unique but identical contentPanes.

Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention something about your use of null layouts.  While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

For instance, when I ran your code, this is the dialog that I saw:

[image]

You hard coded the button's size to be too small to show its text on my platform. If you had used layout managers, and called `pack()` on the top-level window, the button would show appropriately.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the quick response! So it would be something like `public Container panelFactory(){ /*make and return Container*/} and I would call it when I want to get a new one... This button showing up on the Frame really confused me there.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: it was within the JFrame, if only briefly, and so you saw it, but if you repainted the JFrame after creating the dialog, it would likely disappear. For instance when I run your code, I only see the button in the JFrame fleetingly when I press the button in the dialog.

Comment: @geisterfurz007: side issue: you also would never have code that calls main methods as you're doing.

Comment: Oh wow. A perfect timing thanks to my computer. And I assume that including the other dialog caused enough delay to "delete" the button again from the frame? Oh and to the buttons size etc. notice the name of my java file. I have an extra project just to mess around and produces examples to post here in their simplicity. Although I have to admit that I am using the null layout for exactly that reason. This is my first project I am currently working on and I made the mistake I guess to use a GUI-Builder... I try to get better though!